# Acceder a una etiqueta dentro de una clase

Tags: css

Hola quiero acceder a una etiqueta que esta dentro de una clase:

```
<h2 class="easylogo">
  <a href="/" title="Imagen">
   <span style="line-height:0" class="none">
    <img src="imagen.com" alt="Imagen">
   </span>
  </a>
</h2>
```

Como puedo modificar el estilo de la imagen, estoy trabajando en Wordpress y me da la opcion de añadir el CSS adicional, entonces quiero saber como acceder al estilo de esa imagen.
con:

```
img{}
```

Modifico todas las imagenes, pero no quiero modificar todas las imagenes solo esta, entonces como puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una sería como lo siguiente:

```
h2.easylogo img{
   /* Aquí tus estilos */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que no tengas otro elemento con la clase `easylogo`, podrías hacer esto:

```
.easylogo img {
  /* ... */
}
```

En caso que la clase easylogo esté en otra parte de tu código, podrías agregar una clase o id a la imagen (en caso que puedas).